# Instagram Bot: Click Button in Firefox with Selenium Python

Tags: python, macos, selenium, firefox, instagram

I'm making an Instagram Bot (from a YT tutorial) and I can't get past the "Turn On Notifications" pop-up that appears after login.

[I want to click "Turn On"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APxCV.png)

How do I click the button? Here's the xpath and what I see after inspection.

Xpath:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]
```

Inspection:

```
<button class="aOOlW  bIiDR  " tabindex="0">Turn On</button>
```

Here's my code. Can anyone tell me what to add and where? I'm attempting to click the button at the very bottom...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

def print_same_line(text):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.flush()


class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(2)
        login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher']")
        login_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
        user_name_elem.clear()
        user_name_elem.send_keys(self.username)
        passworword_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
        passworword_elem.clear()
        passworword_elem.send_keys(self.password)
        passworword_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)
        notify_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Turn On"]')
        notify_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution!

Instead of using this...

```
notify_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Turn On"]')
notify_button.click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Use this!

```
notify_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("COPY PASTE CSS SELECTOR HERE")
notify_element.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
time.sleep(1)
notify_element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(2)
```